# .css() not setting width value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking to simply move a divs width as certain pictures load in my application. As such for some reason I read the Div's width add 128 and then use the .css() to change divs new width. For some reason the .css() function isn't updating the width as it goes along. It only updates on the last picture that is loaded. I'm really not to sure why this is happening. Here is some code:

```
document.getElementById('back').onload = function(){
    var width = $("#LoadingBar").css("width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    width = parseInt(width);
    var newwidth = width + increment;
    newwidth = newwidth +"px";
    $('#LoadingBar').animate({width:newwidth},"fast");
    if(width == 1280) {
        //This is another div that I show once all the pictures load            
        $("#everything").show();
     }
}
```

Any ideas as to what I am breaking?

Comment: There's a `$().width()` function in the jQuery API I think

Comment: You'll have to explain this better, you're not using `css()` to update anything, it only gets the width when you leave out the second argument ?

Comment: oooo touche... So using the .animate() doesn't set the value and I never actually update the css again with the new value! Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: `animate()` sets the value just fine, but in your question you're specifically claiming you're using `css()` to change divs new width, but without a second argument, `css()` doesn't change anything at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jquery width property to update element widths.

css is for more esoteric properties of your HTML elements.

```
$("#LoadingBar").css("width")
```

Becomes:

```
$("#LoadingBar").width()
```

You can set width too

```
$("#LoadingBar").width(MyWidthValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this to change the width

```
$(<your element>).width(function (a, w) {return w+=128});
```

and this if you need to animate

```
$(<your element>).animate({width:"+=128"},'fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `css width` use: `var width = $("#LoadingBar").width()` to get the numeric value. Then increment it and append units